# Why normal equation can have infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

The normal equation is
$$
X^Ty = X^TX\hat{\beta}.
$$
If $X^TX$ is invertible, then $\hat{\beta}$ has an unique solution which is
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.
$$
However, if $X^TX$ is non-invertible, then $X^TX$ is a singular matrix, which means that $rank(X^TX) = r < p$ where $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix. By the dimension theorem, we know that
$$
rank(X^TX) = rank(X) = r < p.
$$
And then we need to show that the $ker(X^TX) = ker(X)$, and this can be proved by suppose $y \in ker(X^TX)$
$$
X^TXy = 0 \implies y^TX^TXy = 0 \implies ||Xy||^2 = 0 \implies Xy = 0.
$$
Therefore, $ker(X^TX) = ker(X)$. Then we know that there are $p-r$ linealy dependent columns in $X$ and $X$ and $X^TX$ can not span the whole column space of $X$.

**However, I can't figure out that the above can finish the proof of why a normal equation can have infinite solutions?**

Comment: If you want to show the normal equation *can* have infinite solutions, then surely you just need a single example?

Comment: I think there may be formal proof that can show them.

Comment: There's a more basic fact which is that if a matrix $A$ has a nontrivial null space then $Ax = b$ either has no solutions or infinitely many solutions. Do you understand why that's true?

Comment: @ScottJW Presenting a single example (and proving that the example works) is a 100% rigorously logical proof of this statement. Playing around with abstract matrices might give you equivalent conditions that could help you identify an example, but you only truly know that an example exists once you write it down and prove it.

Comment: @ScottJW Suppose $Ax_0 = b$ and $v$ is a nontrivial null vector for $A$. Then $A(x_0 + cv) = b$ for all $c \in \mathbb R$, so there are infinitely many solutions to $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution $\beta$ always exists because the image of $X^T$ is equal to the image of $X^TX$. Now for any $x\in\ker X$ you have that $\beta+x$ is a solution. So whenever $X^TX$ is not invertible there are infinitely many solutions.